# AndroidManifest.xml with key com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME

Tags: android

I am getting this random exceptions on some devices. I wonder what I am doing wrong. Please let me know what more information I can provide for this issue. I am clueless what else I can provide to help make this question more useful. I am getting no hints from my app.

```
0   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The fully qualified name of the implementation of OptionsProvider must be provided as a metadata in the AndroidManifest.xml with key com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME.
1   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2474)
2   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:130)
3   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
4   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
5   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
6   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4847)
7   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
8   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:535)
9   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The fully qualified name of the implementation of OptionsProvider must be provided as a metadata in the AndroidManifest.xml with key com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME.
13  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzbd(Unknown Source)
14  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source)
15  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService.onCreate(Unknown Source)
16  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2458)
17  ... 10 more
18  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The fully qualified name of the implementation of OptionsProvider must be provided as a metadata in the AndroidManifest.xml with key com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME.
19  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzbd(Unknown Source)
20  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source)
21  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService.onCreate(Unknown Source)
22  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2458)
23  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:130)
24  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
25  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
26  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
27  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4847)
28  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
29  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:535)
30  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
31  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
32  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit - **ManifestFile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.mcruiseon.buseeta">


    <!-- For Options menu call support -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <!-- For the background service to run forever -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <!-- For Current Location on Driver App -->
    <permission
        android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- For QR Code -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

    <!-- Google Cloud Messaging -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.mcruiseon.buseeta.InitializingApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${mapsKey}"/>

        <activity
            -- MY ACTIVITIES --
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please share your manifest.xml? Do you have any OptionsProvider or CastContext implementation at your app, (also from dependent lib, module)?

Comment: did you look at this page your manifest is missing some information or you don't have it in there to begin with.  your `CastOptionsProvider` must have it's full name put into that key's value so it knows what to instantiate.  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastContext

Comment: I dont have any activity or calls that uses CastOptionsProvider.

Comment: i believe that is your problem you must declare one and put its identity in your manifest.

Comment: How do I do that ? Can you share some working code ?

Comment: sorry don't know about Cast just go to the link i sited, and start with the code fragment.  i answered your immediate question about the error message.  i believe "write this code for me" is not part of SO.  I'm sure you can google an example as easily as i did that link up there.

Comment: Im not asking "write this code for me", I assumed that you have working code on this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you know how to reproduce this crash ? I am not able to check if what I built will work.

Answer (score 7):

Your app is attempting to connect to the MediaNotificationService somewhere, which relies on the Google Cast SDK. You need to create a class that extends OptionsProvider. Then, you need to register the class you created in your Manifest, like this:

```
<application>
  ...
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
    android:value="com.example.myapp.CastOptionsProvider" />
</application>
```

Information on this can be found here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#initialize_the_cast_context

Comment: I searched for `MediaNotificationService` in my project path, I only found it in `http://localhost:63342/ejc0j33aagk0icfd5p5uzxok4wxbcb1nirr6q/Buseeta/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-cast-framework/9.4.0/AndroidManifest.xml`. I am not using `MediaNotificationService` anywhere else in my manifest or code. I wonder why this creeps in ?

Comment: I did a `gradlew clean` and searched again, I did not find reference to `MediaNotificationService` in the project path. I did a ./gradlew assembleRelease and did the search again, I **could not find** reference to `MediaNotificationService` again in `http://localhost:63342/ejc0j33aagk0icfd5p5uzxok4wxbcb1nirr6q‌​/Buseeta/build/inter‌​mediates/exploded-aa‌​r/com.google.android‌​.gms/play-services-c‌​ast-framework/9.4.0/‌​`.

Comment: Does this fix the exception crash ?

Comment: If you are using the Cast SDK to create a media session, then it will automatically start this service to create the media controls notification. Is this a media player app? If so, you will need to either stop the media session when your app is backgrounded, or you will need to implement the OptionsProvider.

Comment: I do play a mp3 sound on this.. yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
         @Override
         public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context appContext) {

         }
     }



 <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
         android:value="com.example.app.CastOptionsProvider" />
```